# How to change your phone language in Android with Java code?

Tags: java, android, localization

I need help to change my phone language to English United States, using only code in an application.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12954037/3377857

Comment: You cannot change the language for the entire device. At best, using tricks like in the answers, you can have your own application use a different language.

Comment: Are you sure that you can't change the device language using java code in an application

Answer (score 0):

```
    String languageToLoad = "de"; // your language
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```