# how to refresh layout when i press a button

Tags: android, layout, refresh

when i press a button to change a new language from new string values but the layout doesn't changed, how can i do? this is my code:

```
btnChangeLng.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String language = "lo";
            Locale locale = new Locale(language);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Resources resources = getBaseContext().getResources();
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
            Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
            configuration.locale = locale;
            resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, displayMetrics);
            Toast.makeText(Main_Activity.this, "Laos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //refresh here


        }
    });
```

Language will change when i re-open this app, but it's not automatic change when i press a button, now i want to refresh my layout

Comment: try calling the same activity using intent...add flag to clear top

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this Android Localization?
You can refresh your current activity.

[Change language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908289/how-change-language-of-app-on-user-select-language)

Answer (score 0):

First Change the language of device on button click and then fire intent.

```
public void onClick (View v){
 // Chnage lanuage of your device here
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```