# How to change current layout content in previous layout language choose in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

This is my current layout. I want to change content in based upon
previous page selected language.

[image]

When I choose the language the content have changed to selected
language. The important thing is both are having separate class files &layout files. How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Follow this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12954037/4449159. I hope this will help you.

Comment: i want to change layout in based upon selected language.the language choose in previous layout.& changing data is another layout.is it clear? @ Rashmi mathur

Comment: i have another doubt.in languages are get from api.then how to set language in app.@PrashantGosai