# How can I make 'Select your Language' in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-image, android-menu

I'm trying to make an app and I want to make the menu or anything else to choose a language like shown below. Can you help me what should I do list or what ..?

[image]

Comment: You can use Spinners provided by Android: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner

Comment: Do some research and get started. If you have a specific issue, come ask. Until then, just asking "how do I make a language selector" is far too broad.

Comment: ok sorry i didn't know i still new here :) @TheWanderer

Comment: @ShobhitPuri Thank you :)

Comment: I believe the answer you are looking for is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12954037/4587155

Comment: @VytautasBerankis this what i lookt for but is there is method in kotlin ?

Comment: you can paste java code into android studio, it will ask for confirmation and then convert it to kotlin for you.

Comment: Java and Kotlin are very similar. Kotlin is just a different syntax for the JVM, and it's still heavily based on C++/Java. It shouldn't be too hard to manually convert, especially since Kotlin is often simpler to write. And, as @leonardkraemer said, you can usually paste Java code into a Kotlin file and have Android Studio convert it for you. This doesn't always work, however.

Comment: @TheWanderer Good information thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

It is important you learn the very basics when you're trying to find answers. Since this community is designed to help people, I have shared the quickest solution to your question here. I once again encourage you to learn the basics.

Add spinner code in activity layout file.

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Kotlin code

```
    //Lanuages array.
    val languages = arrayOf("English", "French", "Spanish", "Italian", "Portuguese")

    val spinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinner)
        if (spinner != null) {
            val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, languages)
            spinner.adapter = arrayAdapter

            spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, getString(R.string.selected_item) + " " + languages[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

                override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {
                    // Code to perform some action when nothing is selected
                }
            }
        }
```

In strings.xml

```
<string name="selected_item">Selected Item</string>
```

Comment: thank you sure but what basics do you mean ? "kotlin"?

Comment: You can follow up Google documentations first. It'll help you massively. If my code helps could you accept it?

Comment: Your question pointed to creating a spinner not changing App language.