# Language not changing for items in listView (Android)

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an app that uses 2 languages. When i press the button to change language, it changes for the strings in the menu and navigation drawer but does not changes for items in the listView. Here is my code.

```
 private void showChangelanguageDialog() {
    //array of languages to display
    final String [] languages = {"English","Shona"};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.choose_language));
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(languages, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (which == 0){
                //english
                setLocale("en");
                recreate();
            }
            if (which == 1){
                //shona
                setLocale("sn");
                recreate();
            }
            //dismiss alert dialog when language is selected
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}

private void setLocale(String lang) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.locale=locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    //save data to shared preferences
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Settings", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("My_Lang",lang);
    editor.apply();
}

//load saved lanuage in saved preferences
public void loadLocale(){
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Settings",Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String language = prefs.getString("My_Lang","");
    setLocale(language);
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Could you please add your ListView adapter code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try compiling the app as an apk if you are compiling it as an aab. I had the same problem and it was resolved by using an apk before uploading it to playstore

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to call [notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged()) on your list to force it to refresh the views within

Comment: This answer is not helpful at all.

Comment: @TinovimbaMawoyo why is that and do you have a better guess?

Comment: @DwayneT wherever you apply the language change

Comment: @Sean i follewed a tuturiol so i'm not sure exactly where, is it after getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());     ?

Comment: you need to call it on your list adapter... 

But actually I like better @Noah answer  restarting the whole Activity...

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution for your problem should be to restart your Activty as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908289/how-to-change-language-of-app-when-user-selects-language)