# access intent to subtitles

Tags: android, android-intent, settings, subtitle

I'm trying to access the subtitle settings, so I can change them.

But I'm not managing to find a way to access these settings.

[image]

Some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an Intent object like this to open Caption Settings:

NOTE: Minimum API level is 19

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_CAPTIONING_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

For example, if you have a button to open Caption Settings on click.

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_CAPTIONING_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

You can return by pressing back button on device.

Comment: Thx, it works.
I do not understand just why when I change settings, such as text color.
I go back, but the change is not seen.
  I have to close app, and reappropriate it.

Comment: You will need to handle configuration changes. Following links may help you to understand it:

--> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes

--> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832959/android-reflect-ui-language-change-on-the-on-the-fly-without-reload-restarting?noredirect=1&lq=1

--> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908289/how-to-change-language-of-app-when-user-selects-language

--> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908289/how-to-change-language-of-app-when-user-selects-language